Improve Parallelising *Reading, Cropping and Patching* individual .RT-H5 files (using Python **H5py**)
I have a data processing pipeline that is a perfect candidate for parallelisation but I can't seem to get "good" speed ups.
The process that I need to complete is:

Read in a .RT-H5 file from a local directory
Crop the file with supplied Latitude and Longitude limits
Chop each cropped arr into square patches nxn
Save the cropped, patched arr back to a .nc file

Each of the files is independent and requires no data sharing.
I currently have concurrent.futures set up that submits the open, crop, patch and save functionality to a ProcessPoolExecutor(). Using concurrent.futures I get a roughly 50% speed up versus non-parallel. In terms of data, each of the .RT-H5 files is simply 1800x3600 pixels and I have 48 per day. Currently, to run a single month ~ 30*48 = 1440 files, it takes 2 minutes (4 min if I don't use concurrent.futures). I have read a few blogs online about parallelising the H5 files with h5py but I can't get anything to give me more improvements. I have tried DASK and also I have tried the ThreadPoolExecutor but they give me no speed up. I feel like it should be easy. The workflow I want is:

start N threads that each read in the .RT-H5 file
have multiple processes, running the open, crop, patch and save functionality across the threads

Here is my current implementation:
    # data processing: crop, patch and save.
    tasks = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
        for _, v in file_mapping.items():
            # generate raw and save file paths.
            # TODO: think of a better way of handling all the paths.
            file_path = os.path.join(
                config["download_dir"], f"{v}{config['raw_file_type']}"
            )
            save_file_path = os.path.join(
                config["download_dir"],
                f"{v}{config['save_file_suffix']}{config['save_file_type']}",
            )

            tasks.append(
                executor.submit(
                    open_crop_patch_save_wrapper,
                    file_path,
                    config["crop"],
                    config["patch_size"],
                    save_file_path,
                    config["save_file_data_attr"],
                )
            )

where the open_crop_patch_save_wrapper() function looks like this:
def open_crop_patch_save_wrapper(
    file_path: str,
    crop: Dict[str, Tuple[float, float]],
    patch_size: int,
    save_file_path: str,
    h5_data_attr: str,
    ):

    try:
        # 1. crop the file to desired lat/lon lims.
        cropped_arr = create_xarr_from_imerg_hdf5(
            path_to_hdf5=file_path,
            lat_lims=crop["latitude"],
            lon_lims=crop["longitude"]
        )
        # 2. patch the file to (patch_size x patch_size) patches.
        y_max, x_max = cropped_arr.shape
        x_pad = calculate_required_1d_padding(X=x_max, Y=patch_size, frac=0)
        y_pad = calculate_required_1d_padding(X=y_max, Y=patch_size, frac=0)
        patched_arr = create_square_patches_from_2d_arr_using_overlap(
                arr2d=cropped_arr,
                patch_size=PATCH_SIZE,
                x_pad=x_pad,
                y_pad=y_pad,
                flip_pixels=True,
            )
        # 3. save the cropped, patched file.
        with h5py.File(save_file_path, "w") as f:
            f.create_dataset(
                name=h5_data_attr,
                data=patched_arr,
                compression="gzip",
                dtype=patched_arr.dtype,
            )
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        # return file_path if unable to execute (assume file corrupted).
        return file_path

and create_xarr_from_imerg_hdf5 and create_square_patches_from_2d_arr_using_overlap look like this:
def create_xarr_from_imerg_hdf5(
    path_to_hdf5: str,
    lat_lims: Optional[Tuple[float, float]],
    lon_lims: Optional[Tuple[float, float]],
    imerg_version: str = "7",
) -> xr.DataArray:
    # get precipitation key - changes per version.
    imerg_config = IMERGEarlyRunConfig()
    precipitation_key = imerg_config.raw_data_attr[str(imerg_version)]

    with h5py.File(path_to_hdf5, "r") as h5file:
        lat = h5file["Grid/lat"][:]
        lon = h5file["Grid/lon"][:]
        data = h5file[f"Grid/{precipitation_key}"][0, :, :].T

        xarr = xr.DataArray(
            data,
            dims=["latitude", "longitude"],
            coords={"latitude": lat, "longitude": lon}
            )
        
        # slice the array using latitude and longitude.
        slice_params = {}
        if lat_lims is not None:
            slice_params["latitude"] = slice(*lat_lims)
        if lon_lims is not None:
            slice_params["longitude"] = slice(*lon_lims)

        xarr_cropped = xarr.sel(**slice_params)

    return xarr_cropped

and
def create_square_patches_from_2d_arr_using_overlap(
    arr2d, patch_size, x_pad, y_pad, flip_pixels: bool = False
):
    # error handling.
    assert len(arr2d.shape) == 2  # 2d.
    y_max, x_max = arr2d.shape
    assert (y_max >= patch_size) and (x_max >= patch_size)  # sufficient input arr dims.

    if flip_pixels:
        # flip pixels so that (0, 0) is the 0th pixel top-left.
        arr2d = np.flipud(arr2d)

    max_rows = int(np.ceil(y_max / patch_size))
    max_cols = int(np.ceil(x_max / patch_size))
    patches = []
    for r in range(max_rows):
        for c in range(max_cols):
            if (r < (max_rows - 1)) and (c < (max_cols - 1)):
                # no overlap.
                patch = arr2d[
                    (r * patch_size) : (r + 1) * patch_size,
                    (c * patch_size) : (c + 1) * patch_size,
                ]
            elif (r < (max_rows - 1)) and (c < (max_cols)):
                # only longitude overlap.
                patch = arr2d[
                    (r * patch_size) : (r + 1) * patch_size,
                    (c * patch_size) - x_pad : (c + 1) * patch_size,
                ]
            elif (r < (max_rows)) and (c < (max_cols - 1)):
                # only latitude overlap.
                patch = arr2d[
                    (r * patch_size) - y_pad : (r + 1) * patch_size,
                    (c * patch_size) : (c + 1) * patch_size,
                ]
            else:
                # overlap in lat and lon.
                patch = arr2d[
                    (r * patch_size) - y_pad : (r + 1) * patch_size,
                    (c * patch_size) - x_pad : (c + 1) * patch_size,
                ]

            patches.append(patch)

    arr_patches = np.array(patches).reshape(
        (max_rows, max_cols, patch_size, patch_size)
    )

    return arr_patches

Additional Experiments:
def data_prep(i):
    cropped_arr = create_xarr_from_imerg_hdf5(
        path_to_hdf5="<filepath>",
        lat_lims=IMERG_CROP["latitude"],
        lon_lims=IMERG_CROP["longitude"],
        )
    y_max, x_max = cropped_arr.shape
    x_pad = calculate_required_1d_padding(X=x_max, Y=PATCH_SIZE, frac=0)
    y_pad = calculate_required_1d_padding(X=y_max, Y=PATCH_SIZE, frac=0)
    patched_arr = create_square_patches_from_2d_arr_using_overlap(
            arr2d=cropped_arr,
            patch_size=PATCH_SIZE,
            x_pad=x_pad,
            y_pad=y_pad,
            flip_pixels=True,
        )
    save_nc_file(patched_arr, f"test_data/test{i}.nc")
    return True

def thread_worker(process_executor, i):
    future = process_executor.submit(data_prep, i)
    return future.result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xlims = [0, 500]
    ylims = [0, 690]
    input_args = [i for i in range(100)]

    # experiment 1.
    start = time.time()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as process_executor:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as thread_executor:
            # Each input results in multiple threading jobs being created:
            futures = [
                thread_executor.submit(thread_worker, process_executor, i) for i in input_args
            ]
            results = [future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)]
    print(results)
    print(f"parallel (threads & processing) took {time.time() - start}s")

    # experiment 2.
    start = time.time()
    tasks = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
        for i in input_args:            
            tasks.append(executor.submit(data_prep, i))
        results = [task.result() for task in as_completed(tasks)]
    print(results)
    print(f"parallel (just processing) took {time.time() - start}s")

    # baseline.
    start = time.time()
    for i in input_args:
        res = data_prep(i)
    print(f"non-parallel took {time.time() - start}s")

Output:

parallel (threads & processing) took 3.0833849906921387s
parallel (just processing) took 2.998046875s
non-parallel took 9.5276038646698s

Expected much quicker speed up with Threading but I think the files could be locked.
